# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx loading resources 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config

Hy

We're trying to get our website working on kubernetes (running in a container using nginx). We use ingress to route to the site, here is our configuration:

nginx-conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Kubernetes deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mywebsite
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mywebsite
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mywebsite
        image: containerurl/xxx/mywebsite:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mywebsite
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 82
    targetPort: 80

  selector:
    app: mywebsite
```

Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myIngress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xxx.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /mywebsite
        backend:
          serviceName: mywebsite
          servicePort: 82
```

When i go to xxx.com/mywebiste, the index.html is loading, but the css and js are not loaded (404):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="/styles.30457fcf45ea2da7cf6a.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  <body>
  <div id="react-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.171d6a95cf24d8abab14.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

...because it trys to get the resources here, as example of the css:

```
xxx.com/styles.30457fcf45ea2da7cf6a.css
```

...instead of:

xxx.com/mywebsite/styles.30457fcf45ea2da7cf6a.css

If tried different things like:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root
```

...etc., but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a routing problem on nginx part, but the browser trying to access an absolute URI from the root of your domain. Use relative URIs (remove the leading slash):

```
<link href="styles.30457fcf45ea2da7cf6a.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.171d6a95cf24d8abab14.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. I have removed the leading slash but still get the same error. `/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @rakesh have you managed to fix the issue? I am facing the same problem