# Ingress Nginx won't load resources of a Django Application

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

so I have a django application running in K8 but my resource, like .css, won't get loaded. I always receive a 404 on them. I use Ingress-Nginx to route incoming traffic.

**The ingress config looks like this:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-aboi
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-cert
  rules:
  #- host: dev.<ip>.xip.io
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: django-service
          servicePort: 8000
```

For the index.html I tried with leading slashes and without. Because I found this information in this stackoverflow thread here. [Kubernetes Ingress Nginx loading resources 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871970/kubernetes-ingress-nginx-loading-resources-404)
Sadly, it doesn't solve my problem.

**Index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Log in | Django site admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/admin/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/admin/css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/admin/css/responsive.css">
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Before I was using a nginx with this config, but I don't want to use another pod if I can handle the traffic with a ingress-nginx component alone.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
   listen      443 ssl;
   location /media  {
       alias /website/media;
   }

   location /static {
       alias /website/static;
   }
   location / {
       uwsgi_pass  django;
       include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_redirect off;
   }
```

So to sum it up. I can use the app but without resources. The resources are located in one of the django application pods. I checked if they are inside, and so are they. 
I also tried a rewrite snippet like this, to match the nginx config from before. It doesn't work either.

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
     rewrite (.*)/media/(.*) /website/media/$2 break;
     rewrite (.*)/static/(.*) /website/static/$2 break;
```

By the way. If I use a host like xip.io I can't access my application at all. So I really don't know what I messed up at the end. A domain would be nice but more important would it be to be able to load the needed resources.

Any help, tips & tricks are appreatiated.

Kind regards from Berlin.

Comment: What versions of kubernetes and nginx ingress controller are you using? Here is [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#detect-installed-version) to guide how to check nginx version. To check kubernetes version use `kubectl version`.

Comment: Kubernetes 1.14 and latest Ingress Nginx latest 0.26.1.

Answer (score 3):

I learned that static files should not be served by Ingess. It should be handled by a web server like nginx oder a cdn. Ingress is for routing, it should not be treated like a web server. Because I don't want to spin up and extra pod for nginx I'll use a Middleware for the Django application which is called whitenoise for now. This will deliver static files via gunicorn. 
I have to rethink what the best solution will be in the future and will probably use a cdn from Google or AWS.